# Hidden Overflow with 100% Height

Tags: css, overflow

I have a layout that contains 3 main div's: `#nav`, `#footer` and `#shell`.

Inside my `#shell` div is centered, vertical-scrolling content. The `#nav` and `#footer` div's are fixed and sit above `#shell`. The `#shell` div also has some top margin to space it underneath the `#nav` on initial load.

I'd like to try and hide the `#shell` content so when the user scrolls down and the `#shell` hits the navigation, the content is hidden beneath `#nav`. I'd also like to hide the `#shell` content below the `#footer` div. The entire body has a background image so I can't give a solid color to the `#nav` or `#footer` div's because I need the image to stay visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/mr0vc3rq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr0vc3rq/2/)

I'm not sure if this is what you want. But if it's not, I think it's near the answer. Just tweak it to achieve the desired result.

**CSS**

```
#shell {
    top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 90px;
    width: 720px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I did try this solution but still hoping that I can keep the scrollbar to affect the entire browser window's height and not just the height of the #shell with the top and bottom padding.

Comment: I'll try it again. Please wait.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr0vc3rq/5/)

```
   html {
    background: #f1f1f1 url('http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Blue-Blur-Background1.jpg')  no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
header{ background:url('http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Blue-Blur-Background1.jpg')fixed top repeat; width:100%; min-height:60px; position:fixed; background-size:100%;width:100%;max-height:80px; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:2000;}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    width:auto;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: #333;   
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}


/* FOOTER */
#footer-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    background:url('http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Blue-Blur-Background1.jpg')fixed 50% 100% repeat;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
#footer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);

}

#shell {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
```

Comment: Works but you offset the background image with this approach.